# Find remote IP address and port number for a TCP socket using linux command line

Tags: linux, sockets

I have the below entry in `strace` for one of my programs

```
[pid 13759] 08:17:14 sendto(657, "*** Needed to remove the message for confidentiality ***"..., 729, 0, NULL, 0) = 729 <0.000097>
[pid 13759] 08:17:14 recvfrom(657, "*** Needed to remove the message for confidentiality ***", 2048, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("*removed*.*removed*.129.16")}, [28->16]) = 114 <0.000031>
```

The above `sendto` and `recvfrom` systems calls are operating on socket 657. I need to figure out what is the remote IP address and port corresponding to the socket number 657. Can you please suggest the linux command to get the aforementioned information?

One way of doing it is to start the `strace` before the TCP connection is established. The remote IP address and port number are printed in the `connect` system call when the TCP connection is established. I cannot use this approach because in my case (on the prod system) the TCP connection was established much earlier and I cannot really do a restart of the application.

I am using Ubuntu `VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"`.

Help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I understand the answer, but it has not worked for me till now. Paying diligence to the steps to make it work/make sense of why it is not working.

Comment: One question @kaylum, 
Q) For a strace of process 12740 and an entry "[pid 13627] 10:42:01 sendto(612,", should I expect the file entry 612 to exist in "fd" dir of both the processes 12740 and 13627 or one of them? I understand that 13627 (the entry printed in the strace) is an alias for thread ID.